# styling text in a input type check box

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<label>
  <img data-disable-checkbox="true">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  This checkbox value
</label>
```

JQuery

```
$("img[data-disable-checkbox='true']")
  .next()
  .prop("disabled", "disabled")
  .css({"text-decoration":"line-through"});
```

I am using the above jquery code to disable the check box and line through the checkbox text. Checkbox disabling is working but the line through of the checkbox text is not working. How can I reach checkbox text and put a line through?

http://jsfiddle.net/yXVZM/

Comment: You cannot style a text node, you need to wrap it with another element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot style a text node, you need to wrap it with another element

```
var img = $("img[data-disable-checkbox='true']");
img.next().prop("disabled", true);
img.parent().contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text());
}).wrap($('<span />', {
    style: 'text-decoration: line-through'
}));
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fgSx7/)

Comment: Wow, this is probably the most complicated solution to this problem ever. I'm truly amazed that it has been chosen as the answer.

Comment: @ZorleQ both the other solutions had its own problems like adding the style to parent causes a display issue and second one was changing the markup

Answer (score 2):

The code is attempting to add the `text-decoration` property to the checkbox, instead of the `label`.  Find the parent of the element that is of type `label` and apply the style.

```
$("img[data-disable-checkbox='true']").next().prop("disabled", "disabled");
$("img[data-disable-checkbox='true']").parent("label")
                                    .css({"text-decoration":"line-through"});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/yXVZM/4/

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are trying to cross out the checkbox value, and not the entire selector.

**One way** to achieve would be to use parent instead and cross out everything. But that would cross your image as well.

```
$("img[data-disable-checkbox='true']").next().prop("disabled", "disabled")
    .parent()
    .css({"text-decoration":"line-through"});
```

**Alternatively**, you can surround your text with a span, and cross out that.

```
<label>
    <img data-disable-checkbox="true">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <span>
        This checkbox value
    </span>
</label>
```

And:

```
$("img[data-disable-checkbox='true']")
    .next().prop("disabled", "disabled")
    .next()
    .css({"text-decoration":"line-through"});
```